# What are the differences between ISO 19794-2 and ANSI 378 fingerprint template?

Tags: biometrics

I am looking for the differences between the [ISO 19794-2](https://www.iso.org/standard/50864.html) and [ANSI 378](https://webstore.ansi.org/standards/incits/ansiincits3782004) fingerprint templates.

If there are differences, for what types of applications are each of these standards most suitable?

Comment: I googled "ANSI 378 vs iso 19794-2" and got this as a top hit: https://templates.machinezoo.com/  which is a site also referenced by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103773/what-is-fingerprint-template-format

Comment: Thank you for your answer. These 2 links do not explain anything except "the encoding is different". But what impact does this have for a developer who has to choose between these two formats?

Comment: The links also describe that there is no impact. It's just encoding. They are incompatible with each other.